# TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I suddenly start getting this warning on the device when I try to save a new customer to Parse.
"TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined at main.js 16:21"  (line 16 starts with stripe.customer.create)

Main.js code is:

```
//STRIPE
var Stripe = require("stripe")
Stripe.initialize = ("sk_test_uXXXXXXXXXT");

Parse.Cloud.define("saveSCID", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    Stripe.customer.create // main.js line 16
    ({
        source : request.params.token,
        email: request.params.email,
        description: request.params.description,
    }, 
    {
        success : function(err, customer) {
        var Usr = request.user;
        var newcust = Parse.Object.extend("Customer");
        var newUsr = new newcust();
              newUsr.set("sCID", customer.id);
              newUsr.set("parent", Usr);
        var pACL = new Parse.ACL();
              pACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
              pACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
              pACL.setReadAccess(Usr, true);
              pACL.setWriteAccess(Usr, true);
        newUsr.set("ACL", pACL);
        newUsr.save(null, 
            {
                success : function(customer) 
                {
                    response.success("customer saved to parse = " +     Usr.get("username"));
                },
                error : function(error) 
                {
                    response.error("Ops failed to saved customer id ");
                }
            });
        },
        error : function(customer,error) 
        {
            response.error("Error");  
        }
    });
});
```

Parse Log:

```
E2015-09-19T01:46:04.416Z]v25 Ran cloud function saveSCID for user jKyXXXP with:
  Input: {"description":"Andrew Jackson","email":"andrewXXXX@icloud.com","token":"tok_XXXXp"}
  Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
at main.js:16:21
```

In the production version I don't get the same error. I double checked the API keys, they are correct. I have no idea what might be wrong here :/  I will appreciate any help.

Comment: your code starts with `var Stripe = require("stripe")` and then you use `stripe.` instead of `Stripe.`

Comment: @koopajah Thanks for your response. When I use Stripe then it shows this message: (TypeError: Cannot call method 'create') of undefined at main.js 16:21) Can you guess why that happens?

Comment: @Esma see my response below.

Comment: @Ibdakine I changed to 1.5.0 and then to 1.4.2 but it is still the same error :/

Comment: Ah sorry =\ I'm not sure then =\

Comment: @Esma: It's `Stripe.Customers.create` with an `S` for Customers.

Comment: @koopajah I changed it to 'Stripe.Customer.create' getting the same error :/

Comment: @koopajah Actually when it is 'Stripe.Customers.create' I get a different error message: "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isString' at request (stripe.js:49:25) at post (stripe.js:117:12) at Object.module.exports.Customers.create (stripe.js:239:16) at main.js 16:22"

Comment: @Esma: Then try a different version or you'd need to contact Parse directly as they built this integration they might know what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Parse deleted the cloud modules in version 1.6.0. You can revert to 1.5.0 using: `parse jssdk 1.5.0` from your project directory in the terminal. That should fix it.